# How to use LDAP authentication in Geoserver without the @domain.local part after the username?

Tags: geoserver, active-directory

I am trying to configure LDAP authentication against an Active Directory. While I can successfully authenticate with Active Directory accounts on Geoserver, I need to input the usernames in the [user@domain.local] format.

It doesn't seem like a real issue, but I can foresee the general confusion for users trying to connect to Geoserver because all internal services in our organization are using LDAP authentication using credentials like [user]/password and Geoserver would be the exception using [user@domain.local]/password.

[user@domain.local] corresponds to the userPrincipalName while [user] corresponds to sAMAccountName.

I tried a few things in the "Format used for user login name" but I can't get any setting to make it work. It either just doesn't work or I still have to use [user@domain.local]

Below are the settings used in Geoserver:

[image]

Comment: Just set the filter to be `sAMSAccountName={0}` then currently you are saying the first entered value must equal `userPrincipalName` **OR** the second value must equal the `sAMMAccountName`

Comment: I tried [Filter used to lookup user] = (sAMAccountName={0})
and [Format used for user login name]= {0} or just leave it to {0}@domain.local
but now I can't authenticate any ldap user and get an internal server error trying to login.
What should be the correct Filter and Format values?

Answer (score 1):

I have the following set:

```
User lookup pattern: uid={0},ou=users
Group Search base: ou=groups
Group search filter: (memberOf={0})
```

And the rest are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the Active Directory credentials in the [user]/password format with these configs:

[image]

Then I moved up the LDAP authentication provider first in the "Provider Chain" in the "Settings -> Authentication" menu.